# Read device's udid with base SDK 7.0

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, udid

I have to read the iOS device's udid in a project with base SDK 7.0 (I know I'm not supposed to, but I need to read it and the `identifierForVendor` is not an option). I have to to this only on iOS 6 devices, but the method `uniqueIdentifier` is not recognized because of the base SDK. Since I don't know how to determine the iOS version at compile time, I did the following:

```
#define SYSTEM_IS_IOS_7 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
...
    if (!SYSTEM_IS_IOS_7) {
            SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"uniqueIdentifier");
            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
                NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                            [[[UIDevice currentDevice] class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
                [invocation setSelector:selector];
                [invocation setTarget:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
                [invocation invoke];           
                NSString *udid = nil;
                [invocation getReturnValue:&udid];
                NSLog(@"%@", udid);
            }
    }
```

I'm running the code on iOS 6.1, the udid appears on the console, but the app crashes right after that with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the `main.m`, with no message on the console. Any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: If you set the Base SDK to iOS 7.0, the app won't even install on a device with iOS 6. If you read the docs, the `uniqueIdentifier` method will return a 40-character string starting with `FFFFFFFF`, followed by the hex value of `identifierForVendor` under iOS 7.

Comment: The deployment target is 6.0 so yes, it installs on an iOS 6 device. I also Logged the `identifierForVendor` and it is different that the udid. And I neead this to work on an iOS 6 device, on iOS 7 I'm doing a different thing

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html try this

Comment: @Levi Sorry, it's late for me. Ignore my comment about the Base SDK. The other part of my comment is valid. You will not get the UDID by calling `uniqueIdentifier` under iOS 7.